# Problems getting refresh_token from Google calendar API in offline mode using PHP library

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

The first time I sync an account with Google calendar, I get from the API response a response like this:

```
{"access_token":"xxx","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"xxx","id_token":"xxx","created":1519204303}
```

I save this information in the ddbb, and then I can sync the user events in my platform with the user's Google calendar without problems.

In my platform, each event could be sync with the user's calendars, the question is that if the user wants to sync another calendar with another event, when I sent the user to Google Authorization, in this case I don't receive refresh_token from Google Calendar api response:

```
{"access_token":"xxx","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"id_token":"xxx","created":1519204379}
```

So, I'm not able to use it in offline mode.

**Summary:**

First time that the user authorize the usage of an account, it response good. If the user want to sync another event, I sent again to Google auth because he can decide to use another account to sync the calendar with the event, but if he decide to select a previous selected google account, in this case, I'm not able to receive the refresh_token. If I could save the account id or something, I could use old refresh_token information, but in the API response I'm not receiving the account identifier.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Answer (score 0):

When the user authencates your application the first time.   You are given an access token and a refresh token.   The refresh token gives you access to the users Google calendar account.   All of the calendars that the user has access to not just one of them.

Google expects you to save the refresh token for the user.  They will not return to you another refresh token. You are expected to use the one you have saved even if you request authentication of the user again. If you want to force a new refresh token to be given you can do [approval_prompt=force](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#userconsentprompt) or [revoke](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#tokenrevoke) this will prompt the user to authenticate your application again and give you a new refresh token.

Comment: the problem is that I'm not receiving an identifier to identify the selected account.

Comment: Invalid Signature